# Yii add action on transaction rollback

Tags: php, yii, rollback

Is there a way to add an action to a `CDbConnection` when `rollback` action is called ?

I have this code and it works :

```
$transaction = $model->dbConnection->beginTransaction();

try {
    //...
    //doing some manipulations
    //...

    if($model->save()) {
        $transaction->commit();
        $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
    }

} catch(Exception $e) {
    $transaction->rollback();
    throw $e;
}
```

Is there a way reverting the manipulations done when the `$transaction->rollback();` is called without putting this code in the `catch` statement, like adding an event on the transaction rollback function.

Maybe there's a workaround with [Behaviours and Events](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/44/behaviors-events/), but I'm not sure how it works.

Thanks!

**EDIT** - What I want to do is this:

When the model fail to save, there will be a rollback on the database, but I'm doing some manipulations on the files too (that I need to do before validating & saving the model), so if the model fail to save because of the validation, I need to revert theses changes to the files.

Comment: What is it you want to do exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

currently CDbTransaction does not have any events defined.

What I would do, is create class that will handle this logic in a way you can reuse:

```
//protected/components/AtomicTransformation.php
<?php
class AtomicTransformation {
  private $_model;
  private $_transaction;
  public function __contruct(CModel $model)
  {
    $this->_model = $model;
    $this->_transaction = $model->dbConnection->beginTransaction();
  }
  public function commit()
  {
    $this->_transaction->commit();
  }
  public function rollback( /* pass any params you need for your revert logic */)
  {
    // Do your revert logic here
    $this->_transaction->rollback();
  }
}

$transformation = new AtomicTransformation($model);

try {
    //...
    //doing some manipulations
    //...

    if($model->save()) {
        $transformation->commit();
        $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
    }

} catch(Exception $e) {
    $transformation->rollback( /*your params */ );
    throw $e;
}
```

Comment: Nice, I haven't thought of that !